# Замена ближайшей станции метро на произвольную (Яндекс карты)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Хочу создать код так, чтобы Яндекс.Карты отображали не ближайшие к адресу станции метро, а нужные мне. Как можно добавить еще станции метро? [image: Например, здесь я хочу заменить метро "Октябрьское поле" на "Строгино", то как это сделать?]

Comment: Это стандартная карточка в API, её видоизменить нельзя, но можно сделать собственный балун со своей инфой, какая нужна.

Comment: Здравствуйте
Как можно сделать свой собственный балун? Через какой сервис Яндекс? Чтобы сделать так, как мне надо?

Comment: Где можно взять образец кода, чтобы подставить туда свои станции метро?

Comment: @Azat [примеры кода](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan) есть в песочнице Яндекса. Станции метро в в данном случае это просто ваш произвольный html-контент, а не какие-то отдельные сущности API.